# problem using flexbox to space between elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.logo {
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul a {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="nav flexbox">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="container flexbox">
      <ul class="items">
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Home
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    About
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Services
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Team
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Blog
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Contact
                    </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
</header>
```

I need the content of the list to be separated with a justify-content. I am using space-between value but is not working. What is the problem I am facing? It has to do with the element a having a default inline display value? Sorry for questions, I'm new on flexbox.

On the other hand, the visual editor studio code by default placed those rel in element a. What is it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.logo {
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 50%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

ul a {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="nav flexbox">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="container flexbox">
          <ul class="items">
            <li class="item">
              <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
              <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                About
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
              <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                Services
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
              <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                Team
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
              <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                Blog
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
              <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                Contact
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </nav>
    </header>

  </body>
</html>
```

Your code is fine, the problem was the `ul` is getting 100% and there was no space! I have set `.container` width 50% and `.logo` width 50%.

You can go through below links for reference
https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: The second answer is telling me that use space-between isn’t a good option. That’s true?

Comment: No nothing like that! But the space will reduce due to screen sizes. You have to write some media queries or you can give padding on li. If i were you I'd probably go for padding and make both div justify-align: center;

Answer (score 0):

space-between is not good choice. try flex-end and won't think about position menu. Use padding for space

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.nav {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.logo {
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul a {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="nav flexbox">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="container flexbox">
      <ul class="items">
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Home
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    About
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Services
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Team
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Blog
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    Contact
                    </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }        
        .flexbox {
            display: flex;
        }
        .nav {
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: stretch;
            max-height: 50px;
            margin-top: 0;
            background-color: gray;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .logo {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        img {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container {
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        ul a {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<header>
        <nav class="nav flexbox">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <div class="container flexbox">
                <ul class="items">
                    <li class="item">
                        <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <a href="http://" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```